# running android studio on a server/cloud platform?

Tags: android, cloud, self-hosting

I am currently a Computer Science student and have a group project that needs to create an app in android studio. However, over the course of years working on group projects I know many issues can occur from having user based error like it will run for one person but not for the other.
I'm trying to find a free and easy way of creating a remote server either on my computer or on a cloud platform that will host android studio where my group members and I are able to remote in to work on the projects without any hassle. so my question is are there any 3rd party software that does this kind of work? if not, most likely we would have to just deal with it and use github.

Comment: Yes, we are building this solution where Android Studio on a cloud platform. We are launching the private beta in a couple of days. Here is the link for requesting early access. [https://yaoe.io/android](https://yaoe.io/android)

Answer (score 1):

**Update -**

About two years ago, I started building a project with my twin brother that could help us code over the cloud. We began researching for ways to achieve this and began noticing projects like Google’s Stadia that were streaming GPU-intensive games over the internet.

After stumbling upon multiple technologies we began exploring and experimenting with the WebRTC project while scouring through proposals submitted on the IETF regularly.

We eventually zeroed in on streaming our dev tools to our browsers and began developing Neverinstall to help users conserve system resources.

We ran dev tools in a cloud-native environment for a better experience that did not hinder the local machine.We knew we immediately had to validate our project and the need for such a tool.

So, we shared it about 2 years ago to get some quick feedback from devs.

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/j0o51v/introducing_android_studio_on_the_cloud_request/

Beyond our wildest expectations, we received immense support from the developer community along with amazing suggestions and feedback that ultimately helped us evolve the platform into a full-fledged personal cloud computer. So as we grow, we look back at how the community helped us get where we are today, and we do not want to stop delivering.

One of the first dev tools that we started supporting when we built NI was Android Studio. It is a popular dev tool with a large user base and problems alike. We began by addressing one of the most common grievances with Android Studio – slowing computers – and moved to take the experience closer to native.

From launching Beta to releasing full-fledged support for AS, the developer community helped us understand what they need and how we can make NI conducive for Android development.

So, today we are excited to announce that Neverinstall now supports emulators on the platform out-of-the-box. Developers can now build, test, and deploy Android apps in record time, eliminating several hindrances such as slower Gradle build times, sluggish emulator performance, and incompatibility issues.

Try [Android Studio on the browser](https://neverinstall.com/spaces/devtools)

We would love to see you build your Android projects on our platform and give us suggestions on how we can make it better.